# How to pull a dataset combined Header table and Details table without using Cursors or Loops

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables **Orders** and **Order Details** table.  I want to combine both tables data with header and details in a dataset.  When I join these two tables i get combined data but i want a pattern to pull the header first and then the details next without using loops or Cursors.
Here is the example below described.:

ORDER TABLE:

```
OrderID  Orderdate  customerF_name  customerL_name OrderAmount
1001     2/21/2018  abc             def            $3,025
1002     2/21/2018  ghi             jkl            $7,226
1003     2/21/2018  mno             pqr            $5,752
```

ORDER DETAILS TABLE:

```
OrderID  Item       Item_Desc         Item_Amount Quantity
1002     sofa       leather sofa.     $1,900         1
1002     bed        bedset              $800         1
1002     desser     desser              $780         1
1002     dining     120" table..      $3,746         1
1001     cocktail   cocktail tbl set  $1,780         1
1001     Bedset     double bed set    $1,245         1
```

THE EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
1001,2/21/2018,abc,def,3,025
1001,cocktail,cocktail tbl set,1,780,1
1001,Bedset,double bed set,1,245,1
1002,2/21/2018,ghi,jkl,7,226,1
1002,sofa,leather sofa.,1,900,1
1002,bed,bedset,800,1
1002,desser,desser,780,1
1002,dining,120" table..,3,746,1
```

You might have observed the pattern in the output.  The first row for each OrderID is pulled from the Header table and next followed by the details for the same orderId.  This pattern will repeat until the last row of the Header table.

I am actully trying to create a query to produce a flat file in my SSIS ETL process and send the flat file to the users who needed.

Could some one please help me how to write MS-SQL query to achieve the final result.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There is no proper way to do this. One hacky way to do it to fist combine the 2 tables using a union query .Then on the top of this combined data, do a order by orderId. If you want to force the sequence add an extra column with value 1 in the first union query and an extra column with value 2 in the second union sql

Comment: Thanks @Fact.  You are right.  since there are is no proper column indication to join both the tables to produce the required output.  I am looking for some hacky way how to write a sql query.  Thank you though for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select orderid,col2, col3,...,col100 FROM
 (
SELECT orderid,col2, col3,...,col100,1 as Seq from header_table
UNION ALL
SELECT orderid,col2, col3,...,col100,2 as Seq from detail_table
) ORDER BY orderid,Seq
```

Comment: Thanks @Fact I tried your script.  It produces the result as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A union query would probably work.  I'll type something out to show the general idea.  It won't be perfect.

```
select orderId + ',' + firstName + ','
    + LastName + ',' + cast(orderAmount as varchar(10)) row
union
select orderId + ',' + item + ',' + itemDescription + ','
    + Cast(ItemAmount as varchar (50) )+ ',' + cast (quantity as varchar(10)) row

order by row
```

Comment: Thank you @Dan Bracuk.  Your answer is very simple to put everything in one string column and union all.  I have accepted your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
--ORDER TABLE:
Declare @order table(OrderID int,  Orderdate varchar(10), customerF_name varchar(100),  customerL_name varchar(100), OrderAmount money)
insert into @order select 1001,     '2/21/2018',  'abc',             'def',            '$3,025'
insert into @order select 1002,     '2/21/2018',  'ghi',             'jkl',            '$7,226'
insert into @order select 1003,     '2/21/2018',  'mno',             'pqr',            '$5,752'

--ORDER DETAILS TABLE:

declare @order_detail table (OrderID int,  Item varchar(100),      Item_Desc varchar(100),  Item_Amount money, Quantity int)
insert into @order_detail select 1002     ,'sofa     ',  'leather sofa.    ', '$1,900' ,        1
insert into @order_detail select 1002     ,'bed      ',  'bedset           ', '  $800' ,        1
insert into @order_detail select 1002     ,'desser   ',  'desser           ', '  $780' ,        1
insert into @order_detail select 1002     ,'dining   ',  '120" table..     ', '$3,746' ,        1
insert into @order_detail select 1001     ,'cocktail ',  'cocktail tbl set ', '$1,780' ,        1
insert into @order_detail select 1001     ,'Bedset   ',  'double bed set   ', '$1,245' ,        1

declare @output_table table (Col1 varchar(100), Col2 varchar(100), Col3 varchar(100), Col4 varchar(100) ,Col5 varchar(100))
insert into @output_table
select * from @order where OrderId in (select distinct o.OrderId from @order o join @order_detail od on od.OrderId = o.OrderId)

insert into @output_table
select * from @order_detail where OrderId in (select distinct o.OrderId from @order o join @order_detail od on od.OrderId = o.OrderId)
select * from @output_table order by 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Pang and satishcse.  I loved the way you described the script and it is very easy to understand.  Thanks a lot.  I will accept your answer and it solved my problem. Thank you once again.

Comment: Thank you @satishcse for a quick solution.  Your solution is very easy to understand.

Comment: @desi Always HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    select OrderId, CAST(orderdate as varchar(20)) [orderdate], customerF_name, customerL_name, CAST(orderAmount as varchar(15)) [orderAmount] from ORDER_TABLE
    union all
    select orderId, item, item_desc, CAST(item_amount as varchar(15)), CAST(quantity as varchar(5)) from ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE
) a order by orderId, [orderDate]
```

Because of that you have different datatypes in respective columns, you have to use casting :)

Comment: Did you notice that his header and detail rows have a different number of fields?

Comment: Both tables have 5 columns.

Comment: Thanks @Michal.  I am able to pull all results but I think I am missing the order.  But again if I use Fact's script to add one more column with SEQ. and order by I am able to get the result what I expect.

Comment: @desi Happy to hear that. Please, accept answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hack up the data like that why not just do a join

```
select o.*, d.Item, d.Desc, d.Amount, d.Quantity
  from order  o
  join detail d
    on o.OrderID = d.OrderID 
 order 
    by o.OrderID, d.Item
```

Comment: Hi @Paparazzi,   It is our client requirement.
Thanks for your suggestion though.